# HTML PHP: IF li element clicked, ORDERBY DESC or ASC

Tags: php, html, sql, function

I have a ascending and descending list element within my html. If the user clicks on the ascending li I wish for the products in my SQLi to be shown in ascending order, if descending, descending order.

This is what I have come up with, but does not work.

```
<ul align ="center">
              <li name="asc" onclick="AscendingProds()"><a>Ascending to Descending</a></li>
              <li name="desc" onclick="DescendingProds()"><a>Descending to Ascending</a></li>
            </ul>


    <?php

    AscendingProds(){
        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT prds ORDER BY price ASC");
}
    DescendingProds(){
        $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT prds ORDER BY price DESC");
}
```

Comment: For one, your `li` elements `onClick` is attempting to call a JavaScript function,  not your PHP. You need to have your page do a post-back to call the function you need called.

Answer (score 4):

You can't call a PHP function in an onclick event handler.  That's reserved for Javascript and the like.  What you can do, however, is call a an AJAX - using jQuery - function to process the PHP on a separate page and return the results on the current page.

You are also forgetting to display your results. That's if this is all of your code, of course.

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: It s incredible the number of coders that dont follow this rule and mix html and php in an absolute crazy way... upvote

Answer (score 0):

On the development of Web Apps exists two sites, server and client,  the server runs and send necessary data to the client,  always PHP is on server site and html on client site, then you need to make the event on javascript and then send the request to php. You need Ajax, maybe using JQuery or pure javascript events.

Comment: Put effort on answer, may be with some codes and explanations as well.